# spaces in variable name not working php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array

```
[Company] => Demo Company 1
[First Name] => Test
[Last Name] => Lead 1
[Designation] => This is testing title 1
[Email] => email1@yopmail.com
[Phone] => 242377
```

I used extract() function so all the index values will become variable names, I also used {} as there are spaces in variable names. But i dont know why its not working :(
This ${'First Name'} returns blank...below is my code

```
foreach($vals as $value){
extract($value);
echo '<tr><td><a href="edit.php?id='.$LEADID.'">'.${'First Name'}.' '.${"Last Name"}.'</a></td><td>'.$Company.'</td><td>'.$Phone.'</td><td>'.$Email.'</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable names cannot contain spaces. For reference, read the [manual on variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular
>   expression, it would be expressed thus:
>   '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

If I were you, I'd just go with a shorter name on the array, so instead of `$value` use `$v` or similar. You can also use [printf](http://php.net/printf) to make the code more readable:

```
foreach($vals as $v) {
  printf('<tr><td><a href="edit.php?id=%d">%s %s</a></td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><t\
d>%s</td></tr>',
         $LEADID,
         $v['First Name'],
         $v['Last Name'],
         $v['Company'],
         $v['Phone'],
         $v['Email']);
}
```

Comment: Because of this `extract` won't make variables with invalid names.

Comment: Yes u r right, but PHP also allows spaces in variable name and we can access it using {} around it http://blog.riff.org/2008_05_11_spaces_php_variable_names....but dont know why its not working here in my code

Comment: Amit, that's an undocumented feature so it may just as well be a bug. It's never good to rely on undocumented behavior. I usually avoid spaces even in array keys just because it may bite me in the future (spaces is not allowed as element names in HTML, not in MySQL column names, and so on...)

Comment: @AmitPatil: I would suggest that even if you have found a trick to use variable names with spaces that this is extremely bad practice.  Obviously it is not enforced everywhere.  If you really need a visual separator use the underscore character instead.

Comment: I would not rely on extract in the first place. Sometimes you will have to import key value pairs from external data sources like csv files and this will break your code if you use extract.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the spaces before using `extract`:

```
$keys = str_replace( ' ', '', array_keys($vals));
$values = array_values($vals);
$vals = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Then, after `extract` you'd have variables like `$FirstName`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not really need extract.
You can use array indexes in interpolated strings.

```
$sample = array('name' => 'frank, 'age' => 42);
echo "{$sample['name']} is {$sample['age']} years old.";
```

If you can avoid using ${'strange names'} you should do it. If yo REALLY need to do it this way:
Please update your question and tell us HOW $value is defined. Is vals The array from your first code block?

Comment: Its coming from xml file, m accessing some API and converting it to array.